# How to select nested UL element without class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my Joomla template I've created a vertical menu including a dropdown which should "push" the elements below away when opening a submenu onclick. Somehow I don't get it to work..

I am trying to grab the UL inside an LI, but how can I do this in JavaScript without the UL's having a class or ID.

I've come to this yet:

```
function getElements(){
var listitems = {};
for(var i = 0; i< arguments.length; i++){
    var id = arguments[i];
    var item = navigation.getElementsByTagName("li");
    if (item == null)
        throw new Error ("No list items found.");
    listitems[id] = item;
}
return listitems;
}
```

Now I should get something like: (I now the following code is impossible, but it describes what I am trying)

```
var nav = document.getElementById("navigation");
var nestedList = nav ul li ul;
nestedList.onclick(nav ul li ul.style = "display: block";);
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li class="parent">
    <ul><li></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
#navigation ul li ul{display: none;}
```

Now I want it to display: block when clicking on .parent

Thanks!

Comment: What is the variable `content`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cant use jQuery? Just curious.

Comment: Oh excuse me, that has to be navigation.

Comment: Can you please show your markup? Selection questions without markup are basically impossible to answer.

Comment: Well, the Joomla version I am using has Mootools active to..

Comment: @Esteban jQuery is great and all, but basic DOM _traversal_ is not complicated enough to necessitate a whole library.

Comment: @VoogdWD If you already have MooTools, use that http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Utilities/Selectors

Comment: @Mathletics I've added some code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have MooTools included in your page, something like this should work (not a MooTools expert here):

```
$('#navigation li.parent').addEvent('click', function () {
  $('#navigation li.parent ul li ul').setStyle('display', 'block');
});
```

---

*Old post:*

Pure JS (this is not the full code, you have to loop over the elements several times for adding the click listener and applying the styles):

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li ul");
var count = listItems.length;

for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
  var item = listItems.get(i);
  item.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course the easiest is using jQuery or some other library.
To do it with pure JavaScript for modern browsers, use JS [querySelector](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml#.UkXeUIakiP8).
Otherwise you will spend a *lot* of time in this.